# String Encoder with lower-case output

Tags: c#, beginner, interview-questions

Question: Take an input string and output the "encoded" string by using the following rules:

> ```
>  [1] vowels are replaced with number: a->1, e->2, etc
>  [2] consonants are replaced with previous letter b->a, c->b, etc
>  [3] y goes to space
>  [4] space goes to y
>  [5] numbers are reversed
>  [6] other characters remain unchanged(punctuation, etc.)
>  [7] all output should be lower case
>  E.g.: Hello World! => g2kk4yv4qkc!
> ```

My Solution:

```
  /// pre processed conversions for letters
  private static Dictionary<char, char> Convert;

  public static string encode(string stringToEncode) {

     // approach: pre process a mapping (dictionary) for letter conversions
     // use a Dict for fastest look ups.  The first run, will take a little
     // extra time, subsequent usage will perform even better
     if (Convert == null || Convert.Count == 0) BuildConversionMappings();

     // our return val (efficient Appends)
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 

     // used for reversing the numbers
     Stack<char> nums = new Stack<char>(); 

     // iterate the input string
     for(int i = 0; i < stringToEncode.Length; i++) {

        char c = stringToEncode[i]; 

        // we have 3 cases:
        // 1) is alpha ==> convert using mapping
        // 2) is number ==> peek ahead to complete the number
        // 3) is special char / punctunation ==> ignore

        if(Convert.ContainsKey(c)) {
           sb.Append(Convert[c]);
           continue;
        }

        if(Char.IsDigit(c)) {
           nums.Push(c);

           // we've reached the end of the input string OR
           // we've reached the end of the number
           if (i == stringToEncode.Length - 1
              || !Char.IsDigit(stringToEncode[i + 1])) {
              while (nums.Count > 0) {
                 sb.Append(nums.Pop());
              }
           }

           continue;
        }

        // not letter, not digit
        sb.Append(c);
     }
     return sb.ToString();
  }

  // create our mappings for letters
  private static void BuildConversionMappings() {

     Convert = new Dictionary<char, char>();

     // only loop once for both
     for(char c = 'B'; c<='Z'; c++) {
        // add capitals version
        char val = (char)(c - 1);
        val = Char.ToLower(val);
        Convert.Add(c, val);
        // add lower case version
        Convert.Add(Char.ToLower(c),val);
     }

     // special cases
     Convert['y'] = ' ';
     Convert['Y'] = ' ';
     Convert.Add(' ', 'y');

     // vowels
     char[] vowels = new char[] { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
     for(int i = 0;i < vowels.Length;i++) {
        var letter = vowels[i];
        var value = (i+1).ToString()[0];
        Convert[letter] = value;
        Convert[Char.ToUpper(letter)] = value;
     }
  }
```

I was asked this question for an interview and the only feedback I received was building a dictionary was a very poor choice and they were no longer interested in continuing the application process.  I was surprised and disappointed, but I want to improve for the next time.  What should I do better?

Comment: Odd. `Dictionary` would be **exactly** what I would choose for this task and hardly consider it "poor".

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer mhmm... if you'd like to be really strict about it then you don't actually need a dictionary, you could calculate everything on the fly... but why? I'm also wondering about the comment although I don't think using the dictionary itself was wrong but rather the way it's being constructed when you call `encode` and then all rules inside a single method... if a senior dev wrote this code I would send him home ;-] It's neither extendable nor maintainable.

Comment: @t3chb0t agreed. Likely, I'd just have the whole thing constructed with a static initializer since the rules really have no chance of altering during our lifetimes.

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer _since the rules really have no chance of altering during our lifetimes_ - you're joking, right? I'm maintaining such _never altering rules_ at work because apperntly people were thinking the same a couple of... weeks ago! ;-)

Comment: @t3chb0t Yeah, I spoke too generically there. I was thinking of a similar thing I did for a ROT-13 coder. So what really needs to happen here is an enterprise rules engine that gets the codings from a cloud-based data store...

Comment: @whiteshooz - I can give you one advice... ask people next time what kind of code they expect... working (aka quick-n-dirty) - if they expect anything else then there is no way enough time in such an interview to come up with a good architecture. It usually takes hours.. sometimes days and multiple refactorings. Everyone who has ever done that before would know that and would either let you write something that simply works or something that is just interfaces.

Comment: Thank you both for the feedback!  @t3chb0t just to be clear, you would send home a senior dev for not making the code extendable and maintainable?  I agree on it's lack of not being extendable, but it seems rather easy to maintain.

Comment: I would send him home just for the way the dictionary is being initialized... instead of using e.g. a static constructor.

Comment: just to be clear, this was a 60 minute coding challenge.  The feedback I got was: 

[1] _I don't like this. One method to "Build" a Dictionary​, which isn't super needed…then adds both upper case and lower cases to the dictionary._ 
[2] _Then the for loop is boiled down and reads nice but that’s cause all of the work was done in the "building" of the dictionary._

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer there is one more benefit from encapsulating the rules... you can test them separately... but I like the cloud-base solution ;-]

Comment: @t3chb0t a wonderful suggestion about the static constructor for the cache!  Although, I don't believe my code reviewer was even keen to that coding deficiency.

Comment: then you dodged a bullet. The interviewer/reviewer seems very inflexible in their acceptance of differing solutions. Like @t3chb0t said, the odd initialization call in the method itself is a little off-putting, but the approach is pretty solid.

Comment: I should think a thoughful 2-way code review would be the most valuable part of the task. I want to know how you think, plumb your knowledge, the why of your code,  get your thoughts on our "right" answer, etc. I'd say they blew the interview, not you.

Comment: Sounds like you dodged a bullet in that job.

Comment: I'm puzzled by this "encoding". The word generally implies reversibility but you're schema is not reversible since it can't disambiguate encoded vowels and some numbers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are couple of things that might have been done better...

- Initilize the dictionary form a static constructor or call the method to initialize the field. The method should not access it internally but return a dictionary as a result. The field itself should be `readonly`.
- `foreach` could be used to iterate the `stringToEncode`.
- Names of internal variables could be better:

  - `Convert` sounds like a method name. The dictionary should be named `Conversions`.
  - `nums` should be `digits`
  - `sb` should be called `encoded`
- `TryGetValue` could have been used instead of `ContainsKey`
- The dictionary is case-insensitive only because you put all letters there. Instead you should use the `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` and make the dictionary `<string, char>` but this would be inconvenient. You could create your own `IEqualityComparer<char>`. This will cut in half its size .
- I wish more `var` (optional)
- I wish more LINQ

Things that are already good:

- I find using a dictionary was a good choice.
- The use of a `Stack` to reverse the order is very clever.
- Using `StringBuilder` for efficiency is definitely a good choice either.

---

When we apply all suggestions the code could look like this:

Creating the `IReadOnlyDictionary` which returns a result and uses a couple of additional helper variables. No `for` loops.

```
// pre processed conversions for letters
private static readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<char, char> Conversions = BuildConversionDictionary();

private static IReadOnlyDictionary<char, char> BuildConversionDictionary()
{
    var conversions = new Dictionary<char, char>(CaseInsensitiveCharComparer);

    var alphabet = Enumerable.Range('a', 'z' - 'a' + 1).Select(x => (char)x);
    var vowels = new char[] { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
    var consonants = alphabet.Except(vowels);

    // consonants are replaced with previous letter b->a, c->b, etc
    foreach (var c in consonants)
    {
        conversions.Add(c, (char)(c - 1));
    }

    // y goes to space
    // space goes to y
    conversions['y'] = ' ';
    conversions[' '] = 'y';

    // vowels are replaced with number: a->1, e->2, etc
    foreach (var (c, i) in vowels.Select((c, i) => (c, i + 1)))
    {
        conversions.Add(c, (char)('0' + i));
    }

    return conversions;
}
```

The alternative equality comparer (here I'm using a helper-factory from my libraries):

```
private static IEqualityComparer<char> CaseInsensitiveCharComparer =
    EqualityComparerFactory<char>.Create
    (
        (x, y) => StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Equals(x.ToString(), y.ToString()),
        obj => StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.GetHashCode(obj.ToString())
    );
```

The refactored `encode` (which should be `Encode`). What has changed here is that I first check for digits. If it's not one and we have some then *dump* the stack to the builder and clear it, othewise do the rest. Below the loop we have to *dump* it once again in case there are some digits left at the end.

```
public static string Encode(string stringToEncode)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringToEncode)) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(stringToEncode));

    // our return val (efficient Appends)
    var encoded = new StringBuilder();

    // used for reversing the numbers
    var digits = new Stack<char>();

    // iterate the input string
    foreach (var c in stringToEncode)
    {
        if (char.IsDigit(c))
        {
            digits.Push(c);
            continue;
        }

        if (digits.Any())
        {
            encoded.Append(digits.ToArray());
            digits.Clear();
        }

        if (Conversions.TryGetValue(c, out var converted))
        {
            encoded.Append(converted);
            continue;
        }

        // something else, undefined
        encoded.Append(c);
    }

    // "dump" what's left
    encoded.Append(digits.ToArray());

    return encoded.ToString();
}
```

---

I think you cannot do anything else having *only* 60 minutes.

Comment: I cannot begin to tell you how grateful I am you took the time to write such a beautiful, optimized, and improved solution.  It reminds me that in my journey to becoming an excellent software engineer, there will always be much room for improvement.  Thank you for taking the time to help me grow.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure that using a more complex comparer to save a few bytes of RAM is worth it, especially if you need to implement one yourself. What would be the speed implications of the more complex comparer? Seems like an optimization problem either way, where the right choice would depend on context.

Comment: @jpmc26 this time it's not because I want to save RAM. I just didn't want to have ToString all over the place. The comparer encapsulates this very nicely, and come on, a comparer is not rocket science, especially when you have helpers for their creation. I find it's one of the most natural things to use in c# saving tons of typing and errors.

Answer (score 7):

Additional to @t3chb0t real code review, I would like to provide an alternative more object oriented implementaion.

Not sure if that solution is really better / more readable / appropriate for such a small problem - but at least it follows the SOLID principles:

```
public class InputProcessor
{
    private static readonly ICharStreamProcessor[] CharStreamProcessors;

    static  InputProcessor()
    {
        CharStreamProcessors = new ICharStreamProcessor[]
        {
            new VowelCharStreamProcessor(),
            new YCharStreamProcessor(),
            new WhiteSpaceCharStreamProcessor(),
            new ConsonantCharStreamProcessor(),
            new NumberCharStreamProcessor(),
            new DefaultCharStreamProcessor(),
        };
    }

    public string Process(string input)
    {
        var preprocessedInput = (input ?? string.Empty).ToLower();
        var resultBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        using (var enumerator = preprocessedInput.GetEnumerator())
        {
            var continueProcessing = enumerator.MoveNext();
            while (continueProcessing)
            {
                var processor = CharStreamProcessors.FirstOrDefault(p => p.CanProcess(enumerator.Current));

                if (processor == null)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException($"Unable to find appropriate processor for character '{enumerator.Current}'.");
                }

                bool continueProcessingWithCurrentProcessor;
                ProcessResult result = null;
                do
                {
                    var accumulated = result?.Result ?? string.Empty;
                    result = processor.Process(enumerator.Current, accumulated);
                    continueProcessing = enumerator.MoveNext();

                    continueProcessingWithCurrentProcessor =
                        continueProcessing
                        && result.ContinueConsuming
                        && processor.CanProcess(enumerator.Current);
                } while (continueProcessingWithCurrentProcessor);

                resultBuilder.Append(result.Result);
            }
        }

        return resultBuilder.ToString();
    }
}

public class VowelCharStreamProcessor : ICharStreamProcessor
{
    private static readonly string vowels = "aeiou";
    private const int AsciiNumberFor1 = 49;

    public bool CanProcess(char c) => vowels.Contains(c);
    public ProcessResult Process(char c, string accumulate) => ProcessResult.Finished((char)(vowels.IndexOf(c) + AsciiNumberFor1));
}

public class ConsonantCharStreamProcessor : ICharStreamProcessor
{
    private static readonly string consonants = "bcdefghjklmnpqrstvwxyz";

    public bool CanProcess(char c) => consonants.Contains(c);
    public ProcessResult Process(char c, string accumulate) => ProcessResult.Finished((char)(c - 1));
}

public class YCharStreamProcessor : ICharStreamProcessor
{
    public bool CanProcess(char c) => c == 'y';
    public ProcessResult Process(char c, string accumulate) => ProcessResult.Finished(' ');
}

public class WhiteSpaceCharStreamProcessor : ICharStreamProcessor
{
    public bool CanProcess(char c) => c == ' ';
    public ProcessResult Process(char c, string accumulate) => ProcessResult.Finished('y');
}

public class NumberCharStreamProcessor : ICharStreamProcessor
{
    public bool CanProcess(char c) => char.IsDigit(c);
    public ProcessResult Process(char c, string accumulate) => ProcessResult.Continue(c + accumulate);
}

public class DefaultCharStreamProcessor : ICharStreamProcessor
{
    public bool CanProcess(char c) => true;
    public ProcessResult Process(char c, string accumulate) => ProcessResult.Finished(c);
}

public interface ICharStreamProcessor
{
    ProcessResult Process(Char c, string accumulate);
    bool CanProcess(Char c);
}

public class ProcessResult
{
    private ProcessResult(string result, bool continueConsuming = false)
    {
        this.ContinueConsuming = continueConsuming;
        this.Result = result;
    }

    public bool ContinueConsuming { get; }
    public string Result { get; }

    public static ProcessResult Continue(string result) => new ProcessResult(result, true);
    public static ProcessResult Finished(string result) => new ProcessResult(result);
    public static ProcessResult Finished(char result) => new ProcessResult(result.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I love the OO approach!  Maybe in the future, I should flex this type of answer.  I have the ability, but I've always feared it would send a signal that _I create over engineered solutions to simple problems._  Next time, I will make sure to ask the technical stakeholders these sort of questions.  Thank you immensely for taking the time to provide such a cool solution.

Comment: I think it is OK to ask the interviewer what exactly she intends with the question. Should the solution be optimized for performance, development speed, following clean code principles... what ever. That shows also, that you are able to clarify unclear requirements in advance - a very importent ability for software developers ;)

Comment: I like this _edition_ and usually this kind of approach pays off. Especially in large projects where you already can anticipate changes that will come. This could be the second part of the interview for a senior position where you could ask them about the design. It might however be very difficult to come up with somethig like this and make it work during a 60 minutes interview ;-)

Comment: No. Just no. Do not create a ton of objects just to make your code "object oriented." It does not help and makes the code **much** harder to understand. I look at this and my immediate thought is, "What in the heck is any of this doing?" I look at t3chb0t's procedural approach and don't even have to wonder. Also, why are you iterating over an enumerator manually?

Comment: @jpmc26 I have to maintain a piece of $%&§ software that has been build procedurally and implement changes that the business requires every couple of weeks or months... you have to spend hours making sure you're doing the right thing in the right place and then another couple of hours making sure you did it right because every change can break everything else... and it already happened multiple times. Nobody understands that this needs to be rewritten to a more OO solution where we just could put the modules together or create new ones easily. [..]

Comment: @jpmc26 [..] procedural approach works only at the beginning. As soon as you start extending it and adding new features it's about time and the last call to make it OO, modular and future-proof. That's why I find if this was a service processing products or orders etc, it **must** be maintainable and this one is. You need a new rule? You just add it to the list. You want to disable one? You remove it from the list. No debugging... no crossed fingers. The only thing you need to test is the new module. The core-logic does not change.

Comment: @jpmc26: the good thing of that solution is: you dont have to understand the complex part (Process method) if you need to modify / extend the business logic. :)

Comment: @t3chb0t Let me clarify: a procedurally minded approach doesn't mean no objects. It means that that the objects created are primarily simple data containers or only exist to provide late binding of functions. OO doesn't magically make anything "modular" or "future proof" or "maintainable." I have the opposite experience: a massive OO system that's tied into knots by shared state (injected via IoC container) and poor choice of abstraction. We need to stop touting these vague notions as magical incantations that fix everything and focus on *the concrete problems they solve well*, if any.

Comment: @t3chb0t As for your example about rules, that just sounds like nonsense. Your rules can interact in weird ways you didn't expect. A later rule might fail if you remove the rule that handled a type of input. So you'll need to debug and test. I can't see how storing them as a list of objects is much better than a well organized sequence of code statements; you can even get just as much reusability by factoring them out to functions. Where it has an advantage is if the rule list needs to be *based on user input*, but that really only requires dynamically chosen functions, not stateful objects.

Answer (score 4):

You should check the input for a valid string:

```
  if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringToEncode))
    return stringToEncode;
```

The check for `Convert.Count == 0` is a little strange in that `Convert` is a private field and only set in one method where we can assume it will be constructed equally every time it is called:

> `if (Convert == null || Convert.Count == 0) BuildConversionMappings();`

But no real harm done, without that check you could just simplify the call like this:

```
Convert = Convert ?? BuildConversionMappings();
```

---

You can set the capacity of the `StringBuilder` which is a performance improvement:

```
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(stringToEncode.Length);
```

---

You use `continue` a couple of times in your loop:

> ```
>     if (Convert.ContainsKey(c))
>     {
>       sb.Append(Convert[c]);
>       continue;
>     }
>
>     if (char.IsDigit(c))
>     {
>       ...
> ```

If you replace `continue` with `else if` statements it will IMO give a more readable code:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < stringToEncode.Length; i++)
  {

    char c = stringToEncode[i];
    if (Convert.ContainsKey(c))
    {
      sb.Append(Convert[c]);
    }
    else if (char.IsDigit(c))
    {
      nums.Push(c);
      if (i == stringToEncode.Length - 1
         || !char.IsDigit(stringToEncode[i + 1]))
      {
        while (nums.Count > 0)
        {
          sb.Append(nums.Pop());
        }
      }
    }
    else
    {
      sb.Append(c);
    }
  }
```

That said, I think you main method and main loop are quite good and easy to read and understand, and the `Dictionary` idea is just the way to go. But the way you build the dictionary is maybe a little cumbersome.

To the bone you just map between two sets of chars (except for the numbers):

```
  const string keys =    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ";
  const string values =  "1abc2efg3ijklm4opqrs5uvw yy";
```

You could look up by finding the index of chars from the input string in `keys` and fetch the corresponding `value` from `values` (lower case). But that would require two look ups per char, and therefore the Dictionary is much better. A `Dictionary<char, char>` can be build from the above `keys` and `values` in the following way:

```
private static Dictionary<char, char> ConstructMap()
{
  const string keys =    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ";
  const string values =  "1abc2efg3ijklm4opqrs5uvw yy";

  IEnumerable<(char c, char cm)> map = keys.Zip(values, (c, cm) => (c, cm));
  return map.ToDictionary(ccm => ccm.c, ccm => ccm.cm);
}
```

because `string` implements `IEnumerable<char>`

---

Just for the exercise I implemented a quite old school indexed `for`-loop like this:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<char, char> charMap = ConstructMap();

public static string HHEncode(string data)
{
  char[] result = new char[data.Length];

  for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
  {
    if (charMap.TryGetValue(char.ToLower(data[i]), out char value))
    {
      result[i] = value;
    }
    else if (char.IsDigit(data[i]))
    {
      int j = i + 1;
      while (j < data.Length && char.IsDigit(data[j])) j++;

      j--;
      for (int k = 0; k <= (j - i) / 2; k++)
      {
        result[i + k] = data[j - k];
        result[j - k] = data[i + k];
      }
      i = j;
    }
    else
    {
      result[i] = data[i];
    }
  }

  return new string(result);
}
```

The main difference to yours is how I handle numbers

Comment: Personally, I can't stand the `else if` - I treat it like `goto` ;-P

Comment: @t3chb0t: I've never heard that comparison before - but it's your world, I'm only living in it :-). As long as the chain isn't too long (as in the above) I think it's OK. On the other hand: what about five or even ten `if-else` statements vs the same number of `continue`s? I would prefer the first.

Comment: nah, `if`s only have a nice and pretty alignment and are easier to read, you can better use helper variables for their conditions and even better comment them if necessary. This is not possible with `else if` because they are glued to the previous block. This is my theory behind it ;-)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback!  I like many of your suggestions and your usage of LINQ `zip` is sexy!

To explain my choice of using `continue`.  I have a profound dislike for nested `if` statements.  I've found that if there is no reason to stay in the `if` block, I'd rather skip to the next `for loop` iteration.

At the end of the day it's more of a preference like you stated and other people have echoed.

Comment: I am not sold on the idea of the two `const string` **keys** & **values**.  In an interviewing exercise, I do not want to send a signal to my reviewer that I can meticulously enter string values.  Instead, I want to show them I can programmaticly populate the cache.  But I do like seeing the same objective being accomplished using an unique approach.  Cheers!

Comment: @whiteshooz: I do not disagree with you. But on the other hand, never hesitate to use a consistent, easy maintainable and intuitive solution. An interview question is also about creativity and productivity as well as "real" coding skills.

Answer (score 2):

Just FYI, here's what the pre-built (no need for the `BuildConversionMappings` method any more) dictionary would look like:

```
/// pre processed conversions for letters
private static readonly IDictionary<char, char> Convert = new Dictionary<char, char>
{
    { 'A', '1' }, { 'E', '2' }, { 'I', '3' }, { 'O', '4' }, { 'U', '5' },
    { 'a', '1' }, { 'e', '2' }, { 'i', '3' }, { 'o', '4' }, { 'u', '5' },
    { 'Y', ' ' },
    { 'y', ' ' },
    { ' ', 'y' },
    { 'B', 'a' }, { 'C', 'b' }, { 'D', 'c' }, { 'F', 'e' }, { 'G', 'f' }, { 'H', 'g' },
    { 'J', 'h' }, { 'K', 'j' }, { 'L', 'k' }, { 'M', 'l' }, { 'N', 'm' }, { 'P', 'o' },
    { 'Q', 'p' }, { 'R', 'q' }, { 'S', 'r' }, { 'T', 's' }, { 'V', 'u' }, { 'W', 'v' },
    { 'X', 'w' }, { 'Z', 'y' },
    { 'b', 'a' }, { 'c', 'b' }, { 'd', 'c' }, { 'f', 'e' }, { 'g', 'f' }, { 'h', 'g' },
    { 'j', 'h' }, { 'k', 'j' }, { 'l', 'k' }, { 'm', 'l' }, { 'n', 'm' }, { 'p', 'o' },
    { 'q', 'p' }, { 'r', 'q' }, { 's', 'r' }, { 't', 's' }, { 'v', 'u' }, { 'w', 'v' },
    { 'x', 'w' }, { 'z', 'y' }
};
```

Things slightly of note:

- Pascal-case the method name `encode` to `Encode`.
- Simplify the dictionary from the `.ContainsKey`.`[]` combo to a single call to `.TryGetValue`

Comment: I could have manually entered all the mappings, but that didn't seem like the best way to demonstrate my ability to problematically populate the cache.  This was a coding interview after all. =)   I agree the method `Encode`  was not Pascal-case, but it was required to be this way because this problem was verified by [Hackerrank](https://hackerank.com).  They had thier skeleton of the method improperly named.  Lastly, I like your suggestion of using `.TryGetValue()` so I only have to look up the hash once!